# Como confirmar saída da página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Como posso confirmar se realmente o usuário saiu da pagina, pois quando clico no navegador para sair e digo que quero permanecer ele transforma o nome do meu `a` em 1 e depois não volta a ser 0. Alguém tem uma solução? Código abaixo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = closeSession;

function closeSession() {
  if (true) {
    var a = document.getElementById('a');
    if (a.name != 1) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "teste.php",
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
          'nome' : "Rogers2",
          'senha' : "123456"
        }
      });
      return "disconnected";
    }
  } else {
    a.name = 0;
  }
}
</script>
<body>

<p>Close this window, press F5 or click on the link below to invoke the onbeforeunload event.</p>

<a href="teste2.php" onclick="this.name = 1" id="a" name="0">teste2</a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para confirmar você pode usar a função "confirm" do javascript

```
<?php 
session_start();

if ($_POST['action'] == 'logout') {

    unset($_SESSION['nome']);
    unset($_SESSION['senha']);

     /* aqui você coloca o comportamento que 
        você quer no PHP, como gravar dados 
        no seu banco, etc. E retorna um tipo de saída válida, 
        caso tenha efetuado o logout corretamente... */
     $saida = true;

    if ($saida) {
       echo json_encode(array('message'=>'Você saiu do sistema!'));
       die();
    }
}
?>

<script>
sairDaPagina() {
   if (confirm('Tem certeza que deseja sair desta página?')) {
       closeSession();
       location.href = 'teste2.php';
   }
}

function closeSession() {

 $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    data:{
        'nome' : "Rogers2",
        'senha' : "123456",
        'action' : "logout"
        }
    })
     .done(function(retn){
         alert(retn.message);
    });

}
</script>
<a href="javascript:sairDaPagina();">Sair</a>
```

Ou se quiser uma coisa mais bacana, você pode fazer isso através de um modal como do bootstrap, por exemplo:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Já tentei isto mas não obtive sucesso. Mesmo assim agradeço.

Comment: Mas explique melhor o que você quer exatamente para que eu possa te ajudar, pois pelo que entendi na pergunta, você quer uma confirmação de saída de página.

Answer (score 0):

Mude a tag `<a href="teste2.php" onclick="this.name = 1" id="a" name="0">teste2</a>` para que o evento `onclick` somente altere o nome do link caso o usuário confirme que realmente quer sair.

Ela ficará da seguinte maneira:

```
<a href="teste2.php" onclick="if confirm('Tem certeza que deseja sair da página?') {this.name = 1}" id="a" name="0">teste2</a>
```

Para ficar um código mais limpo você pode também declarar uma função dentro do seu script e chamála no onclik:

```
function confirmarSaidaDoUsuario(link) {
    if confirm('Tem certeza que deseja sair da página?') {
        link.name = 1;
    }
}

<a href="teste2.php" onclick="confirmarSaidaDoUsuario(this)" id="a" name="0">teste2</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A melhor solução para isso é você checar a última conexão do usuário, para isso você teria que armazenar a data em que ele fez algo no site e assim checar se ele esta a x segundos/minutos/horas sem se conectar, se ele estiver então ele esta desconectado.